# Как сохранить ответ бота вместе с сообщением юзера в телеграм боте python telebot

Tags: python, telebot, логирование

Всем привет. В процессе создания логирования для бота столкнулся с вопросов - Как сохранять не только сообщения пользователя, но и ответ бота?
Использую следующий код:

```
@bot.message_handler(regexp = 'xnj ltkftim|что делаешь|чем занят|чд')
def What_are_you_doing(message):
    a_log = open(f'users\\log_{message.chat.id}.txt', 'a') #создание тхт лога
    a_log.write(f'{datetime.now()}: {message.text} ответ: {???}\n') #1) время, 
    a_log.close()                                       # 2) сообщение юзера 3) ???
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, random.choice(comands.What_are_you_doing))
```

Что нужно добавить в a_log.write что бы так же сохранять сообщение бота?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(regexp = 'xnj ltkftim|что делаешь|чем занят|чд')
def What_are_you_doing(message):
    response = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, random.choice(comands.What_are_you_doing))
    a_log = open(f'users\\log_{message.chat.id}.txt', 'a') #создание тхт лога
    a_log.write(f'{datetime.now()}: {message.text} ответ: {response.text}\n') #1) время, 
    a_log.close()                                       # 2) сообщение юзера 3) ответ бота
```